# How to calculate the date difference between two dates of leap year in javascript?

Tags: javascript, client-side

How can you calculate the date difference in a leapyear?
Between  28-02-2011 to 02-03-2011 for example.

Comment: Days, months, years, seconds, minutes, milliseconds, picoseconds? What have you tried yourself? Have you tried searching SO or Google first?

Comment: This **is** a real question! just not a wellformed one

Answer (score 2):

```
var milliseconds = new Date('2011-03-02') - new Date('2011-02-28')
```

Comment: To include IE before version #9, use Date.parse('2011/03/02') - Date.parse('2011/02/28')